# How to load a text file in HTML

Tags: html

Is it possible to load a text file via HTML using somthing like the link tag?

I’m sure I have seen this before but couldn’t find any thing.

I am creating a local app and I want to load a CSV data file and don’t want to have to rely on the user choosing the file with a file input.

Comment: When you say you don't want to rely on the user choosing the file with a file input, it sounds like you're talking about two different things. Are you talking about opening a file on your server or a file on the user's computer? For security purposes, you can't access local files in HTML

Comment: It’s a local app. There is no server

Comment: What creates the .CSV file?  Is it part of your site, or will the user be building it in some way?  If it's part of your site, you can load it using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

If you mean like a file on the user's computer...only if the file's contents are saved in a cookie or using localstorage when the file is saved. But if you mean from a website, you can use XMLHttpRequest.

See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp